# How would AJAX jQuery Data be delivered to a Templating Engine?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, node.js, templates

I would like to use data from an ajax get request to populate a handlebars template.

I have a node.js/express4 api call that looks like this:

```
var router = express.Router();
router.route('/stories')
    // get all the stories (accessed at GET http://localhost:4200/api/stories)
    .get(function(req, res) {
        Story.find(function(err, stories) {
            if (err)
                res.send(err);
            res.json(stories);
        });
    });
```

For a mongoose model that looks like this:

```
app.use( '/api', router );
var mongoose        = require('mongoose');
var Schema          = mongoose.Schema;
var StorySchema     = new Schema({
    title: String
});
```

With a JSON response looks like this at `http://localhost:4200/api/stories`:

```
[{"title":"New Title","_id":"53557649f6352439239d20ac","__v":0},{"title":"Another Title","_id":"535576831e194da123ea5f27","__v":0}]
```

And AJAX that looks like this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    function foundAllSuccess(result){
        // do something to get the data to the templating
    }
    $.ajax({
        url: "http://localhost:4200/api/stories",
        method: 'get',
        success: this.foundAllSuccess
    })
});
```

And I found something like this as an example, though it has yet to work:

```
function foundAllSuccess(resJSON) {

    var templateSource   = $("#stories-template").html();

    var template = Handlebars.compile(templateSource);

    var storyHTML = template(resJSON);

   $('#page-container').html(storyHTML);
}
...
    <div id="page-container">
        <script id="stories-template">
            <p>{{ title.[0] }}</p>
        </script>
    </div>
```

When first loading the page (localhost:4200), the following error is logged in the browser console:

```
SyntaxError: syntax error @ http://localhost:4200/:69

Line 69: <p></p>
```

Then, when I refresh the page, this error follows the SyntaxError..

```
GET http://localhost:4200/api/stories [HTTP/1.1 304 Not Modified 3ms]
```

'The API is being called', as the console for node does log:

```
router.use(function(req, res, next) {
    console.log('The API is being called');
    next();
});
```

Comment: Can you show what the JSON response looks like? And what is the specific error you are getting?

Comment: @bantic added the JSON response, and the error message (304 Not Modified). The API is being called, as noted by the console.log